# Add-AzureRmVhd results in error: (409) Conflict

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload an vhd to an Azure Storage account with the following PowerShell cmdlet.  What is really insidious about this error is that it only occurs after many, many minutes of computing hash.  There error description is not helping much either.

```
Add-AzureRmVhd -ResourceGroupName $rsrcGrp.ResourceGroupName -Destination 'https://vmvhdlibrary1.blob.core.windows.net/sp16/SP-SvrImage20169174136.vhd' -LocalFilePath 'k:\Users\Tim\Downloads\vhd\SP-SvrImage20169174136.vhd' -NumberOfUploaderThreads 4  -Verbose  -OverWrite 
MD5 hash is being calculated for the file  K:\Users\Tim\Downloads\vhd\SP-SvrImage20169174136.vhd.
MD5 hash calculation is completed.
Elapsed time for the operation: 00:14:10
Creating new page blob of size 136367309312...
Add-AzureRmVhd : The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureRmVhd -ResourceGroupName $rsrcGrp.ResourceGroupName -Destina ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmVhd], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand
```

Comment: I have tested on my local, there is no issue with this command, and I can upload local vhd file to the specified Storage Blob. If you change a new azure storage account or a new Azure storage container, do you receive the same issue? Please try to change a new account/container, or change a different environment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if there is already a lease present on `SPSvrImage20169174136.vhd`, it would return [409 error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179439.aspx). Please check the **Lease state** and **Lease status** of current .vhd file before you run Add-AzureRMVhd command to add a VHD file and overwrite the destination.

We could check Lease state and Lease status from **Blob properties** in Azure portal.

[image]